# Finding out the unavailable string in a text file

Tags: perl

I am using strawberry-Perl.

I have written a Perl script to find out particular strings in a text file,

============================

(file name: sample.txt)

1. fruit - apple
2. fruit - banana
3. vegetable - potato
4. fruit - orange
5. vegetable - onion
6. vegetable - tomato
7. fruit - grape
8. vegetable - eggplant
9. fruit - strawberry
10. fruit - apricot
11. juice - pineapple
12. rice - long grain

============================

here is my code,

```
#!

my @eatables = ("fruit", "meat", "vegetable");

open(FH, "<sample.txt")  or die "Can't open sample.txt: $!";

sub main(){
 while(my $line = <FH>){
     foreach(@eatables){
        if($line =~ m/$_/){
             print "found: $_ at line $.\n";
         }
     }
 }
 close(FH);
}

main();

1;
```

I am getting the following prints,

```
found: fruit at line 1
found: fruit at line 2
found: vegetable at line 3
found: fruit at line 4
found: vegetable at line 5
found: vegetable at line 6
found: fruit at line 7
found: vegetable at line 8
found: fruit at line 9
found: fruit at line 10
```

Here I need to print "not found: meat" in my console, since the string 'meat' is not available anywhere in the sample.txt. What RE can I use to make this? Or do I need to modify my search logic?

Comment: `else print "not found:"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my @eatables = ("fruit", "meat", "vegetable");
open(FH, "<sample.txt")  or die "Can't open sample.txt: $!";

sub main(){
 my $hash = {"fruit" => 0, "meat" => 0, "vegetable" => 0};
 while(my $line = <FH>){
     foreach(@eatables){
        if($line =~ m/$_/){
             print "found: $_ at line $.\n";
             $hash->{$_}++;
         }
     }
 }

 foreach(keys%{$hash}) {
  print "not found : $_" if $hash->{$_} == 0 ;
 }

 close(FH);
}
```

In this way you can know how many times each string has apear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @eatables        = ("fruit", "meat", "vegetable");
my ($combined_search, $not_found) = (join("|",@eatables)) x 2;

sub main() {
       while(my $line = <STDIN>) {
              $line =~ /($combined_search)/ ;
              print "\nFound: $1";
              $not_found =~ s/$1//g; 
        }
}

  main();
  print "Not found: $not_found";
```